# Notations for one-sided coset spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be its subgroup. What notations are used for the coset spaces $\{gH\,|\,g\in G\}$ and $\{Hg\,|\,g\in G\}?$ What I've written is a bit much to type, and I will be writing about both left and right coset spaces, so I can't just write $G/H$ and ask the reader to understand it as, say, the left coset space.

Comment: You could go for $_GH$ and $H_G$?

Comment: @user1729 Thank you, but I'm already using the notation $_HG$ and $G_H$ for something else so this would be confusing. Is there a deeper reason for such notation, or is it just an ad hoc one?

Comment: I have seen it before, but I cannot remember what it related to (it might have been cosets, but I do not know anymore). You could always change the $_HG$ and the $G_H$ to something else?...

Comment: @Bartek It would be a really good idea to write out the set notation too, rather than rely on "left coset"/"right coset" terminology. Although $gH$ is a *left* coset, a student who is used to calling $xR$ a right ideal of a ring may be tempted to think of $gH$ as a right coset. (Totally off topic: is anyone else bothered that in statistics, a distribution that is "skewed left* is biggest on the *right* side?)

Comment: @rschwieb What you are saying depends on context. If Bartek is writing for undergraduates, then sure, but if he is writing a research paper on groups then it would be silly to assume your audience doesn't know what a coset is!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, one will write $G/H$ for left cosets and $H\backslash G$ for right cosets (but remember to write somewhere that this is what the notations mean).

Comment: Nice hint. I didn't know that notation. +1